# BeautifulSoup nonetype error occurring

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to extract the text from `<p>` tags in html data with the following code

```
for i in data:    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(i, 'html')
    print(' '.join(map(lambda e: e.string, soup.find_all('p'))))
```

where data is a list where each element is a string containing html code.  My problem is that it is working for some examples but for others it gives

```
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string or Unicode, NoneType found
```

For the second line in the above code.  Can anyone explain to me why this would happen.  Or alternatively a way to check and skip over the examples where this error would occur?

Comment: What is `i`? Could you show the whole code you are running?

Comment: What example is failing?

Comment: sorry about that.  I updated the post.  I would just be a string containing html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting all `p` tags that have some text instead:

```
' '.join(el.string for el in soup.find_all('p', text=True))
```